# How to view ACRA exceptions with GoogleDocs in a user-friendly way?

Tags: java, android, exception, google-docs, acra

I'm using ACRA with GoogleDocs. Everything works fine, but I think the output isn't displayed in a user-friendly way. One exception takes the whole monitor size. I want to see a single exception similar to the "Form/Show summary" view. Did I missed a setting option in GoogleDrive?

Or.... If there is a FREE alternative to view messages from ACRA user-friendly, please let me know.

Thanks qd0r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only want the bug tracking account for you, your can try http://www.bugsense.com/ you can make a free account and try it, I am pretty satisfied with it.. it works for iOS and windows phone also...
I used ACRA before but unfortunately the google doc is not a really user-friendly experience from my point of view..

Comment: thanks. it was really easy to set it up. :) i hope the free version will be sufficient for me. i got a 14 day trial atm. and don't know what _exactly_ will be disabeled in the free version.

Comment: Well as far as I know you won't be able to share the project with another bugsense user so you will be the only one that can see the reports and a maximum error reports will be allowed.. I am glad you like it! :)

Comment: I've seen one disadvantage to GoogleDocs. On Bugsense the SharedPreferences aren't visible. It's possible to add "ExtraData" with the SDK. But at first I will try it without the SDK and see how it works with my release build on googleplay. :)